# Changing background-image in CSS with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a simple slider who is just fading a picture over an other. The problem is that the background change only works in the dreamweaver preview but not in the browser.

```
loop = setInterval(function(){
    $("#slider").css("background-image" , "url(/slider" + x + ".jpg)");
    $("#slider > img").fadeOut(2);
    $("#slider > img#" + y).fadeIn(3000);
}, 4000)
```

So it basicly looks like this: Set the background, fade the old pic away, fade the new pic over the background, do it again.
But I can't see why it won't set the background or won't display it at least.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: Where is `x` and `y` set? Do the `img` selectors match any elements? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: It would be useful if you could put a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with a replica of the problem above.

Comment: The path of image will be relative to the current page. Check if it is the expected absolute path you have

Comment: @chridam [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uK5nY/2/) here you go
j08691 nice he tells me that he cant load the pics i think i need the full url let me check that

Comment: oh man there was a / not a \ in the link for the bg im so dumb took me like 5h to find it .____.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `src` attribute of the image like this: `$("#slider > img").attr('src', y);`.
Please check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdv4zmfj/1/).